# Explicitly approximating $\sqrt{2}$ with rationals from left and from right

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

After it is shown in a book "Principles of mathematical analysis - W. Rudin" that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational number then it is shown that if $A$ is set of all positive rationals $r$ such that $r^2<2$ and if $B$ is set of all positive rationals $r$ such that $r^2>2$ then $A$ does not contain the largest and $B$ does not contain the smallest element.

That is done by defining for positive rational $r$ the number $s=r- \dfrac{r^2-2}{r+2}$.

Then it is shown that $s^2-2=\dfrac{2(r^2-2)}{(r+2)^2}$ so if $r$ is in $A$ then $s>r$ and $s$ is in $A$ and if $r$ is in $B$ then $s<r$ and $s$ is in $B$.

Is algebraic expression $\dfrac{r^2-2}{r+2}$ somehow special in this context or even some other algebraic expressions can be subtracted from $r$ "to satisfy the needs" of this construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given $r$, we want $s$ such that $s>r$ if $r^2<2$ and $s<r$ if $r^2>2$. It's natural to pick $s=r-\lambda (r^2-2)$, for some $\lambda>0$ to be determined.

We also want $r$ and $s$ to be both in $A$ or both in $B$, so $\lambda$ must not be too large. Let's compute $s^2-2$:

$$s^2-2=r^2+\lambda^2(r^2-2)^2-2\lambda r(r^2-2)-2=(r^2-2)\left[\lambda^2(r^2-2)-2\lambda r+1\right]$$

So $\lambda^2(r^2-2)-2\lambda r+1$ must be positive. Its discriminant is $8$, so the trinomial (in $\lambda$) has two roots.

If $r^2-2>0$, then both roots are positive as long as $r>0$. So $\lambda$ must be less that the smallest root, which is $\frac{1}{r+\sqrt2}$ (because the trinomial is positive outside of the interval between the roots). That is, we must have:

$$0\lt\lambda\lt\frac{1}{r+\sqrt2}$$

If $r^2-2<0$, there is one positive and one negative root, and the positive root is again $\frac{1}{r+\sqrt2}$, so we must have the same inequality (the trinomial is now positive for $\lambda$ between the roots).

Furthermore, the larger the value of $\lambda$ the better, as we get as far as possible from $r$, thus as close as possible to $\sqrt2$.

Any such value of $\lambda$ will do. Since $2$ is the simplest upper bound for $\sqrt2$, it seems $\dfrac{1}{r+2}$ is the simplest value of $\lambda$. You could also pick $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{r+3/2}$, for instance.

Comment: Very nice and simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is based on Heron's approximation algorithm: 
For small $h$, we have $f(x+h)\approx f(x)+hf'(x)$, so picking $h=-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is a promising choice to make $f(x+h)$ small. 
Here, we can consider $f(x)=x^2-2$, so that $f'(x)=2x$. This gives us the recursion
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-2}{2x_n}=\frac {x_n}2+\frac 1{x_n}.$$
Note that this makes
$$x_{n+1}^2-2=\frac 14x_n^2+1+\frac1{x_n^2}-2=\left(\frac{x_n}2-\frac1{x_n}\right)^2, $$
i.e., we will always (except perhaps for $x_1$) have an over-estimate - but we can always obtain $\frac 2{x_n}$ as an under-estimate from it.

Comment: Can it be shown that $\dfrac{r^2-2}{r+2}$ is a good choice without theorems from theory of derivatives?

Comment: You don't *need* the theory of derivatives to discover these formulas, you just need geometry and algebra. Certainly Heron did not have our modern theory of derivatives. Once you have the formulas, you can *prove* that this sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$, using almost nothing but the axioms of the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks

> Is algebraic expression $\dfrac{r^2-2}{r+2}$ somehow special in this context or even some other algebraic expressions can be subtracted from $r$ "to satisfy the needs" of this construction?

Ans: Subtracting $(r^2 - 2)/(r + k)$ also satisfies the "needs" when $k^2 \gt 2$.

Furthermore, we can apply the algebraic algorithm , say twice (composition), and get results that 'move faster' towards the square root of $2$; this would work equally well in Rudin's argument,

## $\quad s = r -  2(\frac{r^2-2}{2 r + 3})$

For a discussion, see the next section.

---

If $k \ne \pm \sqrt 2$ consider the function

$\tag 1 F(x) = \frac{2+kx}{k+x}$

The function $F$ satisfies

$\tag 2 F(\sqrt 2) = \sqrt 2 \text{ and } F(-\sqrt 2) = -\sqrt 2$

So these are fixed points of the function $F$. It is likely that Rudin was aware of the theory surrounding these functions; they are [linear fractional transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation) of a specific form. Functions of the form $F(x)$ can be used to construct sequences of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt 2$.

Also $F(x) = x - (x^2 - 2)/(k + x)$.

Rudin selected $k = 2$ which satisfies $k \gt \sqrt 2$. Moreover, theory tells us that Rudin could have selected $k$ to be any rational number such that $k^2 \gt 2$ and everything would work the same. In fact, with such a $k$ suppose we have positive rational numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2 \lt 2 \lt q^2$. Then

$\tag 3 \displaystyle{\bigcap_{n \ge 0}\, \big [F^n(p), F^n(q)\big] = \sqrt 2}$

with the nested closed intervals all containing $\sqrt 2$.

Interestingly, things work out differently (sequence alternating but still converging) when $k^2 \lt 2$.
For example, let $k = \frac{1}{2}$. Then

$\tag 4 \text{If } r = \frac{11}{10} \text{ then } r \lt \sqrt 2 \text{ and } F(r) = \frac{51}{32} \gt \sqrt 2$

$\tag 5 \text{If } r = \frac{51}{32} \text{ then } r \gt \sqrt 2 \text{ and } F(r) = \frac{179}{134} \lt \sqrt 2$